# logic symbol for 'unlike, differing from'

Tags: mathematical-language, formal-semantics, lambda-calculus

I'd like to express 'unlike, differing from', in an 'academic/professional' fashion using logic symbol(s) or mathematical operators. The descriptions of the corresponding Unicode block seem to show that there's not one symbol for it.

I guess it is related with formal semantics/linguistics.

Example: Unlike set B, set A contains X (or X belongs to A).

Comment: Are you asking for permission? Or confirmation that your conjecture about Unicode is correct? Or is it about math symbols? I don't see an actual question here.

Comment: I'm assuming OP is looking for a mathematical symbol and has tried finding one by checking what uniciode symbols there are for math stuff (but hasn't found anything yet).

Comment: If you're not working specifically in mathematical logic or formal semantics, it's preferable not to use such symbols. Professional mathematicians generally avoid symbols like the universal quantifier, existential quantifier, conjunction, disjunction, etc. unless they're working on logic. They write out these concepts in words: for all, for some, and, or, etc.

Comment: _Unlike_ and _differing from_ are not the same relation; and both of them require some standard(s) to be compared, and a mode of comparison. There is no way to translate "Unlike A, B" into logic because _unlike_ is not a functor.

Comment: @Review What about this question would be a "translation or localization request"? It is a question about formal semantics, so it's totally on topic.

Comment: @lemontree It's a request to translate the natural language word "unlike" or "differing from" into formal logical semantics.

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, if you word it that way, yes, but I'm sure that's not what was intended when banning translation and localization requests. I think the point of it is to rule out "I have this sentence from Chinese please translate into English", not "How could this meaning be accounted for formally".

Comment: @lemontree I don't think either belong here. This site is getting bogged down in un-systematic questions on single words.

Comment: @curoiusdannii I share your concern about single-word questions, but in this case I think it's a positive contribution to the site in that it's a mostly language-independent (= linguistic rather than philological) question.

Comment: @lemontree Perhaps, but then I'd want to see a language independent definition of "unlike". I'd have no problem with a question asking how to convert from NSM to symbolic logic for example. But the question as currently phrased is still heavily based on English.

Comment: @curiousdannii Proposing a language-independent definition/logical representation was the purpose of my answer :) It should work roughly equivalently for *contrairement à*, *toisin kuin*, ... There needs to be some language to start with and in this case it was English, but the concept is a universal one and that's why I deem it a very linguistic question.

Comment: @lemontree It's never safe to assume any concept is universal. Perhaps there is some specific sense of "unlike" used in formal semantics, but the English word itself can't be converted into formal semantics without a thorough definition first.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hi, regarding NSM, what would be, for you, the prime for **disimilarity**? Could you, please, add a thorough answer explaining your view? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GJC Sorry I voted to close the question. I think it is close enough to a translation question. Even if I didn't, I couldn't answer the question without you first giving a clear definition of what you're wanting expressed in formal logical semantics. If you forced me to, I'd guess NOT LIKE, but I wouldn't write an answer for that.

Comment: Excuse my naïveness, but, apparently, in view of the example you offer, what you are after is not a formal symbol expressing the two-place relation of 'unlikeness' or 'difference' (otherwise what would be wrong with the non-identity symbol "≠" ?) but one that expresses a THREE-place relation of unlikeness/difference between x and y IN RESPECT z, is that right? If so, as far as I know, there isn´t such a unique symbol; you will have to use some 'paraphrasis' in one of the logical languages (depending on the nature of x, y and z, entities, sets, etc.).

Comment: @Sibutlasi 'some 'paraphrasis' in one of the logical languages'            Could you post an answer with those paraphrases in as many logical languages as possible? Thnx in advance.

Comment: @ GJC Lemontree has already told you how to express 'A is unlike B in respect R' in propositional and predicate logic. His suggestions suffice, as far as I can tell. (The reason why I made my earlier comment is that the title of your question is a bit misleading, in my view; it does not correspond to what the example you gave calls for).

Comment: @Sibutlasi What title would have fit best for my question?

Comment: @GJC Well, maybe 'Is there a symbol standing for f = 'x unlike y wrt z' ?, but such a symbol is not likely to exist because it is unnecessary and logicians tend to be technically austere. I am not saying that 3-place functions  like that (or  'distance from x to y via z') cannot be 'abbreviated' if necessary. A prodigal logician might want to invent symbols like 'D-i' or 'D-v' to avoid writing lambda expressions with just such functional meanings, respectively, but, in principle, that seems to me otiose and improbable. However, I am no logician or mathematician and I may be completely wrong.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>(Why is there still [no MathJax support for this SE](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/509/use-of-latex-commands)?! Googling and copy-pasting unicode symbols every time you want to talk about semantics is really annoying.)</sub>

---

What you want to say is basically

```
¬φ(a) ∧ φ(b)
```

("The satement `φ` involving `a` is not true, but it is true involving `b`" = "Unlike `a`, statement `φ` applies to `b`).
<sub>Note that my `a` corresponds to your set *B* and vice versa.

Note also that `φ(a)` is not meant to denote a one-place predicate `φ` applyig to some individual `a` - in this case, convention would be to use the letters `P`, `Q`, ... to denote such predicates, and you would not either use an individual constant `a` to denote a set - but simply an abbreviation for some term `a` occcuring somewhere in a formula `φ`.</sub>

---

Let's tackle the question with propositional logic first:

There is a rarely used symbol `↚` (an arrow from right to left with a strike-through, reflecting the negation of a backwards implication `→`) expressing that relation. You could use that one; however, as expemlified by the two truth tables below, this very uncommon symbol can be reduced to simply `¬p ∧ q`:

```
p ↚ q  ¬p ∧ q
1 0 1  01 0 1
1 0 0  01 0 0
0 1 1  10 1 1
0 0 0  10 0 0
  *       *
```

Applied to your example, `p` would denote "the property applies to set B", while `q` would denote "the porperty applies to set A". As you can see, the statement only gets true if `p` is false and `q` is true. (The colums with the star below contain the truth values of the final expression.) If you compare these two columns, it gets obvious that the two statements are equivalent (= have the same permutation of truth values, namely `0 0 1 0`).

So you could use `p ↚ q` to abbreviate "p is not true, but q is".

---

Going back to predicate logic, using this relation, you can express

> Unlike set *B*, set *A* contains *x*

as

```
B∍x ↚ A∍x
```

which is equivalent to

> *B* does not contain *x*, and *A* does contain *x*

```
¬(B∍x) ∧ A∍x
```

If you want to swap sides, you can use the reverse arrow

> *A* contains *x*, unlike *B*

```
A∍x ↛ B∍x
```

This should do the job for you.

But again, it's way simpler to just write

```
A∍x ∧ ¬(B∍x)
```

meaning

> *A* contains *x*, and *B* doesn't.